# Trigger to update sum from another table MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database which keeps track of stats and averages for a league i'm in. I have a results table and a standings table, where I add the "points" from results to an overall "points" in standings. I currently have a query which successfully adds the points from the results to the standings table. However, when I add new results, the standings doesn't update.

Here is my query which I use to SUM the points from the results to standings.

```
UPDATE standings s,( SELECT team_id, sum(points)  as mysum
FROM results GROUP BY team_id) as r
SET s.points = r.mysum
WHERE s.team_id = r.team_id;
```

I'm attempting to use a trigger to update the overall points automatically.  I'm new to triggers, and am receiving syntax error #1064 when I run the following.

```
CREATE TRIGGER standingsUpdate
AFTER INSERT ON results
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE standings s,( SELECT team_id, sum(points)  as mysum
    FROM results GROUP BY team_id) as r
    SET s.points = r.mysum
    WHERE s.team_id = r.team_id;
END
```

Would anybody be able to point me in the right direction? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks,
- Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger should be referencing *new*:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER standingsUpdate
AFTER INSERT ON results
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE standings s
        SET s.points = s.points + new.points
    WHERE s.team_id = new.team_id;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Be careful, though.  You should also have `update` and `delete` triggers.

If you can do this by just aggregating the points when you need them, then that is a better solution (or at least simpler).

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that worked perfectly. The update query is much simpler as well. In regards to your recommendation, what would be an ideal update trigger, say if I made an error during my insert? Would it essentially be the same trigger, just with "AFTER UPDATE ON"?

Comment: @JasonKarlavige . . . A similar query.  You have to subtract the old value and add the new value.